# Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /etc/jmx_exporter/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, jmx-exporter

I'm trying to add JMX exporter on my kafka-zookeeper. For this I've followed these steps:

- copied `jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar` to the current directory
- mounted volume with `/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar:/etc/jmx_exporter`
- and added the argument like this: `KAFKA_OPTS: -javaagent:/etc/jmx_exporter/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar=7071:/etc/jmx_exporter/kafka_config.yml`

I'm downloading [jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.20.0.jar](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/prometheus/jmx/jmx_prometheus_javaagent/0.20.0/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.20.0.jar) from here https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/releases/tag/0.20.0. And remaning it to `jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar`.

Here is the complete `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.6'
name: "kafka-zookeeper"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.0
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
      - "9997:9997" # JMX port for Zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9997          # JMX port for Zookeeper
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost # JMX port for Zookeeper

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.3.0
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9998:9998" # JMX port for Kafka
      - "7071:7071" # JMX Exporter port
    volumes:
      - /jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar:/etc/jmx_exporter  # JMX exporter mount
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL://kafka:29092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9998          # JMX port for Kafka
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost # JMX host for Kafka
      KAFKA_OPTS: -javaagent:/etc/jmx_exporter/jmx_prometheus_javaagent.jar=7071:/etc/jmx_exporter/kafka_config.yml # JMX exporter config
```

**Right now, I'm stuck and don't know what to do with it? I surely can't use other solutions, as everything is self hosted, on top of that having multiple dashboard to monitor stuffs will be really absurd.**

Complete log at pastebin: https://pastebin.com/NWyYuxs6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using helm chart for kafka, with the following details:

image:

```
image:
  registry: docker.io
  repository: bitnami/kafka
  tag: 3.5.0-debian-11-r4
  digest: ""
```

And it has builtin JMX support to it. All I had to do is, enable it:

```
  jmx:
    ## @param metrics.jmx.enabled Whether or not to expose JMX metrics to Prometheus
    ##
    enabled: true
```

Answer (score 1):

> don't know what to do with it

You need to run Prometheus server and setup a `scrape_config` to point at `kafka:7071/metrics`

Otherwise, you can open `localhost:7071/metrics` to see the metrics that are being gathered by the exporter

> surely can't use other solutions

You could. Such as MiniKube + Strimzi, rather than Docker Compose, which comes with JMX exporter already

Comment: Ended up using helm chart... They have a field that needs to be set to true, that's all... Thanks, really appreciate your support... Exploring other options as well, you mentioned here...